# CSS Background-Size doesn't work with static color

Tags: html, css

I am very bad in CSS and I need to accomplish something complicated for me.

I got a table with data and I have a column where I have something like `Qty Assigned / Qty Requested`. I calculate the % assigned so 5 assigned of 10 will be 50%. Now, I want to put a background-color on the `TD` who match the %. So 50% will be half of the TD in let's say red.

I have tried to use `background-color: red; background-size: <?php echo $BgPct; ?>%;` but it doesn't work.

Anyone have solutions ? I can use whatever. I have jQuery also. I don't care if it's CSS1/2/3, but it need to be accurate so 66% isn't a background picture of 75%.

Comment: `background-size` is for images, not background colours.

Comment: maybe you can try with some red background-image, and then use background-size.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović You mean I create an image with the height of a TD and I size the width with the % ?

Comment: Something like that. Or try repeat bg image. Important part is background-size, which you can use only with images.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović Worth the short to try it out even if I found another solution. The image % is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place a div inside another div. Make both divs have the same height. The inner div will have a background color (red). Then you can set the width of the div some % and thats how much it will be filled in.

This is how twitter bootstrap implements its progress bars. If you want a vertically filling bar I think you can set the height to a % and make the widths the same.

Here is the twitter bootstrap example:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/twitter-bootstrap-progress-bars

Click the details tab to see the source code.

A basic implementation example:

```
<div style="width:50%">
    <div style="width: 50%; background-color:red; text-align:center">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: And I put my text in the inner ? A div with X % and another one float hover with the same property with the text ?

Comment: Yes, you can place text in the inner div.

Comment: Your technic was working, but the text space was also the same as the width space. If width is 0%, the text will overflow. This is how I did it to manage it to work : `<td style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><div style="float: left; width: 50%;"><div style="width: 100%; height: 34px; background-color: lightgray; text-align:center">&#160;</div></div><div style="float: left; position: absolute; padding: 8px;">25 / 50</div></td>`

Answer (score 22):

You can use `linear-gradient` for this

For example, if you need 50% of red

```css
td {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, transparent 0);
}
```

Demo:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.half {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, transparent 0);
}

.one-third {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 33.33%, transparent 0);
}

.three-quarters {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 75%, transparent 0);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="half">50%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one-third">33%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="three-quarters">75%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Zero `0` second value is used intentionally to avoid duplicating first value. This works because next value in gradient can't be less than previous.

Comment: how can you do vertical?

Comment: but how can I have it centered?

Comment: @Dani Could you please post it as separate question with desired image and paste link here? I don't understand how you want it to look in the end.

Comment: don't worry it's fine. I was just thinking on it, but thanks

Comment: ok, I had to do some changes and I need to use gradient now. Created the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824113/linear-gradient-with-custom-size

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in comments, I have had good success with a single pixel `background-image` that is stretched to the appropriate percentage `background-size` of the table cell. This works in all modern browsers (IE9+).

This has the advantage (over using an additional `div` element to contain the "colored bar") of being independent of any other styling you might want to apply to the table cell, such as `text-align`, etc. It will naturally appear behind the cells content and flexes to fill the table cell if using percentages.

#### CSS:

```
td.bargraph {
    background:transparent url(/img/dot-green.gif) 0 center no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<td class="bargraph" style="background-size:<?=$perc?>% 80%"><?=$perc?>%</td>
```

Where `$perc` is your calculated percentage.

Answer (score 0):

I would put a `div`, colored red, inside each of the `td`s you want to effect. Then use jQuery to get the number (string) inside the `td` and make it into a variable, which you can then use to set the width of the `div`.

Comment: Yes, it will work. But you have to consider that a text need to be apply in the TD.

Comment: Yeah, i guess you would put the text in the div also