# Angular 7, two-way data binding

Tags: css, angular, dynamic, data-binding, styles

I have one input box and user can give the number and according to that number i want to set the width of background color.

Box width will be fix I just want to change the width of backgrond colour as per the number enter by user

Comment: can you put some images of what you wanna achieve? or a little bit more explaination?

Comment: The width of the background color? HTML elements have widths, CSS properties do not.

Comment: There is no such thing like `width of background color`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use linear-gradient ([Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dgxb46?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)):

```
  <input
    type="number"
    [(ngModel)]="width"
    [style.background]="
      'linear-gradient(to right, red ' + width + '%, transparent 0)'
    "
  />
```

Reference: [CSS Background-Size doesn't work with static color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747325/css-background-size-doesnt-work-with-static-color)